# install pycuda in ubuntu 14.04 with cuda 7.0

Tags: python, pycuda

i am trying install pycuda with cuda 7.0 no problem and run code nice but i can't install and run pycuda after install pycuda with [Installing PyCUDA on Ubuntu Linux](http://wiki.tiker.net/PyCuda/Installation/Linux/Ubuntu) try run simple code with pycuda simple code is

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy

mod = SourceModule("""
___global___ void doublify(float *a)
{
   int idx= threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y*4;
   a[idx] *= 2;
}
""")
a = numpy.random.randn(4,4)
a = a.astype(numpy.float32)
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu,a)

func = mod.get_function("doublify")
func(a_gpu, block=(4,4,1))

a_doubled = numpy.empty_like(a)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(a_doubled, a_gpu)
print a_doubled
print a
```

but code not run and show this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pupuol/Documents/educuda.py", line 3, in <module>
import pycuda . autoinit
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycuda-2015.1.3-py2.7-    linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/autoinit.py", line 2, in <module>
import pycuda.driver as cuda
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pycuda-2015.1.3-py2.7-    linux-x86_64.egg/pycuda/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
from pycuda._driver import *  # noqa
ImportError: libcurand.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such    file or directory
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a library path issue.
Try this before you run python.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64
# or somewhere else your cuda library is located
```